# Dependency failure: Zend Utils extension must be loaded

Tags: macos, server

Zend Utils extension must be loaded!

I have tried installing zend server 8.5 & 7.0 on MacOS Sierra version 10.12.1, the installation process completes without any errors or warning but when running zend server i get the following error:

Message:
Zend Server failed during initialization: Dependency failure: Zend Utils extension must be loaded
Dependency failure: Zend Utils extension must be loaded

Also the screen grab:
[ZendServer Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGIFX.png)

Please assist me on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to mentioned i have found a solution from zend forum

http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=128598

Hope it helps someone.